# Adding Coreplot Graph UIViewController to another UIViewController's view

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, core-plot, subview, addsubview

So I am having an issue with Coreplot.

I am currently attempting to add my Coreplot graph that i implemented within one of my UIViewController's subviews.

I implemented the Coreplot graph in a UIViewCOntroller class and attempted to add the coreplot viewcontroller's ".view" to the subview of another Viewcontroller.

```
ScatterPlotViewController *scatterPlot = [[ScatterPlotViewController alloc] init];
[graphView addSubview:scatterPlot.view];
```

Where graphview is a small uiview among a few other's inside my mainview controller.

[CorePlot example](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13269/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-1)

The example implements a 3 graphs but currently I just implemented one (the scatter plot) without using storyboard. The graph displays fine when I ask the main view controller to push to another viewcontroller

```
ScatterPlotViewController *scatter = [[ScatterPlotViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:scatter animated:YES];
```

I am lost :(.

I tried to read several more similar questions but all lead me to using the HOSTVIEW or

```
graphView = [(CPTGraphHostingView *) [CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 296, 200, 120)];
graphView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:graphView];

ScatterPlotViewController *scatterPlot = [[ScatterPlotViewController alloc] init];
[graphView.hostedGraph.hostingView addSubview:scatterPlot.hostView.inputView];
```

I have changed this around a few times, channging

```
scatterPlot.hostView.inputView to scatterPlot.view
```

changing

```
graphView.hostedGraph.hostingView to graphView.view
```

And several others.

Here is the entire code for the class I used, it is basically the entire code that is used in the tutorial link. I also didn't use storyboards like the tutorial. I just used the code.

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"
#import "CPDConstants.h"
#import "CPDStockPriceStore.h"

@interface ScatterPlotViewController : UIViewController <CPTPlotDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, strong) CPTGraphHostingView *hostView;
```

.m

```
#import "ScatterPlotViewController.h"

@implementation ScatterPlotViewController

@synthesize hostView = hostView_;

-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - UIViewController lifecycle methods
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self initPlot];
}

#pragma mark - Chart behavior
-(void)initPlot {
    [self configureHost];
    [self configureGraph];
    [self configurePlots];
    [self configureAxes];
}

-(void)configureHost {
    self.hostView = [(CPTGraphHostingView *) [CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    self.hostView.allowPinchScaling = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:self.hostView];
}

-(void)configureGraph {


    // 1 - Create the graph
    CPTGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.hostView.bounds];
    [graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme]];
    self.hostView.hostedGraph = graph;


    // 2 - Set graph title
    NSString *title = @"Portfolio Prices: April 2012";
    graph.title = title;


    // 3 - Create and set text style
    CPTMutableTextStyle *titleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    titleStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    titleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    titleStyle.fontSize = 16.0f;
    graph.titleTextStyle = titleStyle;
    graph.titlePlotAreaFrameAnchor = CPTRectAnchorTop;
    graph.titleDisplacement = CGPointMake(0.0f, 10.0f);


    // 4 - Set padding for plot area
    [graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingLeft:30.0f];
    [graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingBottom:30.0f];


    // 5 - Enable user interactions for plot space
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
}

-(void)configurePlots {


    // 1 - Get graph and plot space
    CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;

    // 2 - Create the three plots
    CPTScatterPlot *aaplPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    aaplPlot.dataSource = self;
    aaplPlot.identifier = CPDTickerSymbolAAPL;
    CPTColor *aaplColor = [CPTColor redColor];
    [graph addPlot:aaplPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];
    CPTScatterPlot *googPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    googPlot.dataSource = self;
    googPlot.identifier = CPDTickerSymbolGOOG;
    CPTColor *googColor = [CPTColor greenColor];
    [graph addPlot:googPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];
    CPTScatterPlot *msftPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    msftPlot.dataSource = self;
    msftPlot.identifier = CPDTickerSymbolMSFT;
    CPTColor *msftColor = [CPTColor blueColor];
    [graph addPlot:msftPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];

    // 3 - Set up plot space
    [plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:aaplPlot, googPlot, msftPlot, nil]];
    CPTMutablePlotRange *xRange = [plotSpace.xRange mutableCopy];
    [xRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1.1f)];
    plotSpace.xRange = xRange;
    CPTMutablePlotRange *yRange = [plotSpace.yRange mutableCopy];
    [yRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1.2f)];
    plotSpace.yRange = yRange;

    // 4 - Create styles and symbols
    CPTMutableLineStyle *aaplLineStyle = [aaplPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
    aaplLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.5;
    aaplLineStyle.lineColor = aaplColor;
    aaplPlot.dataLineStyle = aaplLineStyle;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *aaplSymbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    aaplSymbolLineStyle.lineColor = aaplColor;
    CPTPlotSymbol *aaplSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
    aaplSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:aaplColor];
    aaplSymbol.lineStyle = aaplSymbolLineStyle;
    aaplSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(6.0f, 6.0f);
    aaplPlot.plotSymbol = aaplSymbol;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *googLineStyle = [googPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
    googLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0;
    googLineStyle.lineColor = googColor;
    googPlot.dataLineStyle = googLineStyle;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *googSymbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    googSymbolLineStyle.lineColor = googColor;
    CPTPlotSymbol *googSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol starPlotSymbol];
    googSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:googColor];
    googSymbol.lineStyle = googSymbolLineStyle;
    googSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(6.0f, 6.0f);
    googPlot.plotSymbol = googSymbol;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *msftLineStyle = [msftPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
    msftLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0;
    msftLineStyle.lineColor = msftColor;
    msftPlot.dataLineStyle = msftLineStyle;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *msftSymbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    msftSymbolLineStyle.lineColor = msftColor;
    CPTPlotSymbol *msftSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol diamondPlotSymbol];
    msftSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:msftColor];
    msftSymbol.lineStyle = msftSymbolLineStyle;
    msftSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(6.0f, 6.0f);
    msftPlot.plotSymbol = msftSymbol;
}

-(void)configureAxes {
    // 1 - Create styles
    CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTitleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    axisTitleStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    axisTitleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    axisTitleStyle.fontSize = 12.0f;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *axisLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    axisLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;
    axisLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTextStyle = [[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init];
    axisTextStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    axisTextStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    axisTextStyle.fontSize = 11.0f;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *tickLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    tickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    tickLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *gridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    tickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];
    tickLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;


    // 2 - Get axis set
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) self.hostView.hostedGraph.axisSet;


    // 3 - Configure x-axis
    CPTAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
    x.title = @"Day of Month";
    x.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
    x.titleOffset = 15.0f;
    x.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    x.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
    x.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    x.majorTickLength = 4.0f;
    x.tickDirection = CPTSignNegative;
    CGFloat dateCount = [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] datesInMonth] count];
    NSMutableSet *xLabels = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:dateCount];
    NSMutableSet *xLocations = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:dateCount];
    NSInteger i = 0;
    for (NSString *date in [[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] datesInMonth]) {
        CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:date  textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
        CGFloat location = i++;
        label.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(location);
        label.offset = x.majorTickLength;
        if (label) {
            [xLabels addObject:label];
            [xLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:location]];
        }
    }
    x.axisLabels = xLabels;
    x.majorTickLocations = xLocations;


    // 4 - Configure y-axis
    CPTAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
    y.title = @"Price";
    y.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
    y.titleOffset = -40.0f;
    y.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    y.majorGridLineStyle = gridLineStyle;
    y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    y.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
    y.labelOffset = 16.0f;
    y.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    y.majorTickLength = 4.0f;
    y.minorTickLength = 2.0f;
    y.tickDirection = CPTSignPositive;
    NSInteger majorIncrement = 100;
    NSInteger minorIncrement = 50;
    CGFloat yMax = 700.0f;  // should determine dynamically based on max price
    NSMutableSet *yLabels = [NSMutableSet set];
    NSMutableSet *yMajorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];
    NSMutableSet *yMinorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];
    for (NSInteger j = minorIncrement; j <= yMax; j += minorIncrement) {
        NSUInteger mod = j % majorIncrement;
        if (mod == 0) {
            CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", j] textStyle:y.labelTextStyle];
            NSDecimal location = CPTDecimalFromInteger(j);
            label.tickLocation = location;
            label.offset = -y.majorTickLength - y.labelOffset;
            if (label) {
                [yLabels addObject:label];
            }
            [yMajorLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:location]];
        } else {
            [yMinorLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:CPTDecimalFromInteger(j)]];
        }
    }
    y.axisLabels = yLabels;
    y.majorTickLocations = yMajorLocations;
    y.minorTickLocations = yMinorLocations;
}

#pragma mark - Rotation
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}

#pragma mark - CPTPlotDataSource methods
-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot {
    return [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] datesInMonth] count];
}

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    NSInteger valueCount = [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] datesInMonth] count];
    switch (fieldEnum) {
        case CPTScatterPlotFieldX:
            if (index < valueCount) {
                return [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:index];
            }
            break;

        case CPTScatterPlotFieldY:
            if ([plot.identifier isEqual:CPDTickerSymbolAAPL] == YES) {
                return [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] monthlyPrices:CPDTickerSymbolAAPL] objectAtIndex:index];
            } else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:CPDTickerSymbolGOOG] == YES) {
                return [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] monthlyPrices:CPDTickerSymbolGOOG] objectAtIndex:index];
            } else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:CPDTickerSymbolMSFT] == YES) {
                return [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] monthlyPrices:CPDTickerSymbolMSFT] objectAtIndex:index];
            }
            break;
    }
    return [NSDecimalNumber zero];
}
```

Any help is fine!!!

Just need to get this darn app working correctly :P

Answer (score 0):

Placing one view controller under another requires special handling. Read the "Implementing a Container View Controller" section in the *Overview* of the [UIViewController class docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try (??):

```
ScatterPlotViewController *scatterPlot = [[ScatterPlotViewController alloc] init];
[(yourViewController *) addChildViewController:scatterPlot];
[graphView addSubview:scatterPlot.view];
[scatterPlot didMoveToParentViewController:(yourViewController *)];
```